# Making a div placed exactly below another inside a container with all member having relative position

Tags: html, css

The Problem:

- Footer div not placed below content div.
- (update) the container had extra 100px, because of -100px(content). (need to remove 100 px from container)

Structure:

- Container/wrapper contains: menuBar div, content div, and footer div.
- all member `position:relative;`

Details:

- Menu div is overlay
- Content div is using `top:-(height of menu)`
- Footer div use `top:0;`

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Neolitz/ucegu9h4/)

Solution: after a while, I saw that the menubar should be absolute instead of relative. The problem exist because of the `-100px(height of menu)`, so the solution is not using negative value and use absolute instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your content is not long enough to force footer to bottom.  You can do the following:

-declare a height for your footer: 30px

```
.footer{
background-color:red;
position:relative;
top:0;
height:30px;
}
```

-set the container margin-bottom to negative the footer height (-30px)

```
.container{
background-color:darkblue;
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%; /* make width 100% in screen*/
display:inline-block; /* make width follow its content if streched more*/
margin: 0 auto -30px;
}
```

You also have an extra unclosed  in the footer

Footer needs to be moved so that it is a sibling of container instead of a child

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ucegu9h4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i do not want my footer to be at the bottom of the screen, all i need is to make my footer placed below my content div.
so the red block should be below the orange block without and space (blue)

Comment: Oh ok... see updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucegu9h4/4/)... all you had to do was set the footer **top: -100px** to account for the content top: -100 that you set.  If you want to remove all of the blue, then set the <hr> to have no margin by including **hr { margin: 0 }** in the stylesheet

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, yeah that works fine, but this add another problem too, i've add it in my main question.